# creating html buttons in c# from an arrayList

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

I have a productList in my c# where I am trying to create a button for each product in productList...Here's c#

```
        foreach(string product in ProductList)
        {
            Button button = new Button();
            button.ID = "blah";
            button.Text = "hi";
            //button.Attributes["src"] = "trash.png";
            
            button.Click += new EventHandler(button_click);
            place.Controls.Add(button);
        }

  private void button_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

and here's the HTML

```
   <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="place" /><br />
```

I don't understand why the button does not show up on the webpage. BTW this is MVC .net web page in case you didn't already get that

Please help :)

Comment: It looks like Asp.net Web forms rather MVC. Is it really an MVC app?

Comment: @Ramesh what's the difference?

Comment: Initially Asp.Net was web forms where you create .aspx pages and event handlers to the page and controls. Asp.Net MVC follows MVC design pattern where you add controllers, view and models. In MVC you cannot add event to control like web forms.  Please refer https://www.seguetech.com/net-web-forms-vs-mvc/ to understand more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, this screams as being homework... Regardless you need to set up a counter when you go through your Product List.  Showing all of your code will likely help with questions in the future.

```
    List<string> ProductList = new List<string>();
    int i;
```

I assume that your list and variables are not being shown.  And having the code in the page load helps too.

```
       protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ProductList.Add("Milk");
        ProductList.Add("Food");
        ProductList.Add("Cooked");
        ProductList.Add("Beef");

        foreach (string product in ProductList)
        {
            Button button = new Button();
            button.ID = this.ProductList[i].ToString();
            button.Text = this.ProductList[i].ToString();
            //button.Attributes["src"] = "trash.png";
            place.Controls.Add(button);
            i++;
        }

    }
```

Comment: why are we adding increment, if it is a foreach loop and not a for loop?

Comment: Also, this is not hmoework... it's for work but stackoverflow sometimes help when I am trying stuff outside of my knowledge